# Groups of order $p^3 q$ : $q$ divides $p^2-1$ or $p^3-1$ if there is no normal subgroup of order $q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Greetings fellow mathematicians :)

First things first: Yes, this is a homework assignment :-P

Given a group $G$ of order $p^3q$ for two distinct primes p and q, I have to show that $q$ divides $p^2-1$ or $p^3-1$ if there is no normal subgroup of order $q$ in $G$.

According to Sylow, I know that the number of subgroups of order $q$, namely, $n_q$, can only be $1, p, p^2$ or $p^3$ and $n_p = 1$ or $q$. The premise is that $n_q \neq 1$. So to show the claim, I just have to show that $n_q \neq p$ and Sylow does the rest, since if $n_q = p$, we get that $q \mid p-1$ and if we can rule this option out, the only other possible options are $n_q = p^2 \implies q \mid (p^2 -1)$ and $n_q = p^3 \implies q \mid (p^3 - 1)$.

I assume that $n_q = p$, which implies that due to Sylow $p = r*q + 1$ for some $r \geq 1$. Now if $n_p = q$, we get that by the same means as before $q = s * p + 1$ for some $s \geq 1$. This implies that $q = s * (r*q+1) + 1 = srq + s + 1$ which is a contradiction since both $r$ and $s$ are at least 1.

So $n_p = 1$, which means that the Sylow-p-Group is normal in $G$. Let $K \triangleleft G$ be that subgroup. We know that $|K| = p^3$.

This is where I fail to continue. I already tried the following: We know that there are $p(q-1)$ Elements of order $q$ in $G$ and $p^3-1$ Elements that have as their order a power of $p$. If this is supposed to classify all elements in $G$, we get that $p^3-1 + q(p-1) + 1 = p^3q$ which leads to $p(q-1) = p^3(q-1)$ which then implies that $p=1$, so there is a contradiction. But how could this be true? Why aren't their elements with order $pq$ or $p^2q$? I see that there can be no elements with order $p^3q$ because then $G$ would be cyclic, which implies abelianness, which implies that all subgroups are normal. This cannot be the case since the link I posted below implies that there are simple groups with order $p^3q$.

So I have no clue how to continue from there. How does $K \triangleleft G$ lead to a contradiction? Or maybe it doesn't and I can somehow still show that $q \nmid p-1$? I've searched the internet a lot for this but I cannot find a decent clue. The closest question that I found was: [A group $G$ with $|G|=p^3q$ and with no normal Sylow subgroups is $G \cong \mathbb S_4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/932314/a-group-g-with-g-p3q-and-with-no-normal-sylow-subgroups-is-g-cong-math) 
But this question already assumes that $G$ is simple so we can rule out $n_{p,q} = 1$ from the beginning. I cannot use that assumption.

Any hint on the solution will be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at this the wrong way. Note that it is essentially trivial that if $q|p-1$ then $q|p^2-1$ and $q|p^3-1$.

Comment: Oh god, how could I not see this. 'Trivial' is not enough to describe how simple the solution is. Thank you very much, I was stuck in my way of thinking for far too long by now :)

Comment: @Felix We all have moments like that ...